# Selecting entries from a matrix without using a loop

Tags: matlab, matrix, indexing

I have two matrices `A` and `B`, both of which are `Nx3` matrices.

I'm currently getting the maximum value and index for each row of matrix A using:

```
[maxA, idx] = max(A, [], 2)
```

`idx(j)` indicates which column contained the maximum for row `j`.  Now I'd like to select those same positions from matrix B.

I've currently implemented this using a loop:

```
for j = 1:numel(idx)
   maxB(j) = B(j, idx(j))
end
```

My current implementation is fast enough, although I prefer to avoid unneeded loops so is there a way to express this without a loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can build a vector of linear indices (I expect B to be the same size as A):

```
vec_indices = sub2ind(size(A), 1:numel(idx), idx);
```

Then you can use that vector directly for lookup:

```
maxB = B(vec_indices)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can construct the single dimension index into the matrix and get them that way.  All multidimensional matrices in matlab can be addressed.

You can use

```
maxB = B(sub2ind([1:length(idx)]',idx(:)));
```

Answer (score 0):

In one line:

```
maxB = B(A == max(A, [], 2) * ones(1, 3));
```

But this is not safe. It assumes unique values in every row of `A`.